# how to rescale the weight of the feature map in caffe?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

In the paper of '[Inside-Outside Net: Detecting Objects in Context with Skip Pooling and Recurrent Neural Networks](http://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2016/papers/Bell_Inside-Outside_Net_Detecting_CVPR_2016_paper.pdf)'

they are using the skip connection concept to concat roi-pooled features of the layer conv3, conv4, conv5, but before the concatenation, they propose to use L2 NORM and rescale each feature map extracted from these layers, the question to me is how to determine the re-scaling values for the pooled feature, which caffe layer can be used to implement this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use existing layers to compute `L2` norm of a feature map. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36283863/1714410) for and example.
You can use [`"Scale"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/scale.html) layer to scale each feature map.

Comment: they mentioned 'we normalize the pooled features to make sure the downstream values are at reasonable scales when training is initialized. Specifically, features pooled from ’conv3’, ’conv4’, and ’conv5’ are initialized with scale to be 57.75, 81.67, and 81.67 respectively'.  if i use one bottom then the scale is learned , if I used a fixed scaling factor, then I should put it into the bottom 1 while bottom 0 as the input feature ?

Comment: look at the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44762207/1714410): using `lr_mult` you can decide whether caffe learns (and changes) the scale parameter or keep it fixed. it's up to you. @user824624

Comment: additional question, which is more related to the paper, how do I know which exact value to initialize like what they do in the paper

Comment: @user824624 I didn't read the paper. You'll have to figure it out yourself. But having caffe learn this scale value does not sound like a bad idea to me.